# Possible to watch all Intents/Broadcasts on the phone

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there an app or another possibility to watch for ALL Intents and Broadcast flowing in an android system?

Maybe another app which uses a special intent (not the standart ones) you want to use or broadcast yourself.

Comment: I seriously doubt you can listen for all intents/broadcasts without AT LEAST rooting.

Comment: logcat is a good place to start

Answer (score 3):

You can't listen to every `Intent`.

If you are worried that someone else uses your `intent` use your package name as prefix.
For example if you are willing to have an `intent` with the action `SERVER_UPDATE`, use: `com.nitromouse.appname.SERVER_UPDATE`

Answer (score -1):

why not? Just list all permitted intents in the intent filters section. If you find that intimidating, write a program to write the xml menifest (or may be pay someone for typing)?
Oh.. dont forget to add all required permissions also...